# Firebase storage: Allow authenticated users to download files

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have limited the storage of firebase, to only allow authenticated users to read and write from Firebase console. All my project requests are working except the download page of PDF files. I'm suspecting i didn't add the authentication listener in the correct way.

This is my code for my Adapter and my Activity:

**Download Activity:**

```
public class pdfDownloader extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseFirestore db;
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListner;
    FirebaseUser mUser;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    ArrayList<DownModel> downModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    MyPdfAdapter myAdapter;
    public static final String TAG="LOGIN";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pdf_downloader);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mAuthListner = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if(mUser != null) {
                    dataFromFirebase();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG,"AuthStateChanged:Logout");
                }
            }
        };
        setUpRV();
        setUpFB();
        dataFromFirebase();
    }

    protected void onStart() { // allowing users to see the links
        super.onStart();
        if(mUser == null) {
            dataFromFirebase();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,"AuthStateChanged:Logout");
        }
    }

    private void dataFromFirebase() {
        if(downModelArrayList.size() > 0)
            downModelArrayList.clear();
        db.collection("files")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        for(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot: Objects.requireNonNull(task.getResult())) {
                            DownModel downModel= new DownModel(documentSnapshot.getString("name"),
                                    documentSnapshot.getString("link"));
                            downModelArrayList.add(downModel);

                        }
                        myAdapter= new MyPdfAdapter(pdfDownloader.this,downModelArrayList);
                        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(pdfDownloader.this, "Error ;-.-;", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
    }

    private void setUpFB(){
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    }

    private void setUpRV(){
        mRecyclerView= findViewById(R.id.recycle);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

**Download Adapter:**

```
public class MyPdfAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
    pdfDownloader pdfDownloader;
    ArrayList<DownModel> downModels;
    FirebaseFirestore db;

    public MyPdfAdapter(pdfDownloader pdfDownloader, ArrayList<DownModel> downModels) {
        this.pdfDownloader = pdfDownloader;
        this.downModels = downModels;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(pdfDownloader.getBaseContext());
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.elements, null, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyViewHolder myViewHolder, final int i) {
        myViewHolder.mName.setText(downModels.get(i).getName());
        myViewHolder.mLink.setText(downModels.get(i).getLink());
        myViewHolder.deletePdfBtn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                deletepdf();
            }
        });

        myViewHolder.mDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                downloadFile(myViewHolder.mName.getContext(),downModels.get(i).getName(), ".pdf", DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,downModels.get(i).getLink());
            }
        });
    }

    private void deletepdf() {

        db.collection( "files" ).document()
                .delete()
                .addOnSuccessListener( new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                    }
                } );
    }

    public void downloadFile(Context context, String fileName, String fileExtension, String destinationDirectory, String url) {
        DownloadManager downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) context.
                getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
       request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, destinationDirectory, fileName + fileExtension);
        downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return downModels.size();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```